# Replace spaces differently depending on outside or inside single quotes

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, quotes

I have input which has some fields

- separated by spaces,
- some other are enclosed in quotes and also seperated by spaces

Here is an example input:

```
active=1 'oldest active'=0s disabled=0 'function call'=0
```

I would like to replace :

- all spaces outside quotes by `|` and
- all inside quotes by `_`

Output would be:

```
active=1|'oldest_active'=0s|disabled=0|'function_call'=0
```

I tried different solutions with `sed` or `perl` found on the web but did not managed to do want I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ s="active=1 'oldest active'=0s disabled=0 'function call'=0"
$ echo "$s" | perl -pe "s/'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)| /|/g; s/ /_/g"
active=1|'oldest_active'=0s|disabled=0|'function_call'=0
```

Two step replacement:

- First, `'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)` will skip all patterns surrounded by `'` and replace the remaining spaces with `|`
- Second, the spaces now left inside `'` will be replaced with `_`

Alternate solution:

```
$ echo "$s" | perl -pe "s/'[^']*'/$& =~ s| |_|gr/ge; s/ /|/g"
active=1|'oldest_active'=0s|disabled=0|'function_call'=0
```

- Inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40249679/4082052)
- `'[^']*'/$& =~ s| |_|gr/ge` replace all spaces in matched pattern `'[^']*'` using another substitute command. The `e` modifier allows using command instead of string in replacement section
- the remaining spaces are then taken care with `s/ /|/g`

Further reading:

- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html
- http://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html
- http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html

Comment: Wow, what a quick and efficient answer ! Thanks for the explanation also. Is there a good documentation of all parameters available (like SKIP, ...) ?

Comment: see http://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html and http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html

Answer (score 1):

Using gnu awk `FPAT`, you can do this:

```
s="active=1 'oldest active'=0s disabled=0 'function call'=0"

awk -v OFS="|" -v FPAT="'[^']*'[^[:blank:]]*|[^[:blank:]]+" '{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) gsub(/[[:blank:]]/, "_", $i)} 1' <<< "$s"

active=1|'oldest_active'=0s|disabled=0|'function_call'=0
```

- In `FPAT` regex we use alternation to create fields of all single-quoted values+non-space value i.e. `'[^']*'[^[:blank:]]*` OR non-whitespace values i.e. `[^[:blank:]]+` from input.
- Using `gsub` we just replace all spaces with `_` since we will only get spaces inside single quotes in all the fields.
- Finally using `OFS='|'` we delimit output with `|`

**Reference:** [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)

Comment: Good catch @Sundeep. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ":a;s/^([^']*('[^ ']*')*[^']*'[^' ]*) /\1_/;ta;y/ /|/" file
```

This first replaces all spaces in  quoted strings by `_`'s and then translates the remaining spaces to `|`'s.

Answer (score 1):

@anubhava's solution calls to mind a old-school perl solution:

```
$ echo $s | perl -047 -pe "(\$.%2)?s/ /|/g:s/ /_/g;"
active=1|'oldest_active'=0s|disabled=0|'function_call'=0
```

divide the lines by single quotes (047) and sub based on even/odd.

Comment: no need to use double quotes... `perl -047 -pe '($.%2)?s/ /|/g:s/ /_/g;'`

Comment: true. sign of a bash amateur.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the regular expression inside the loop.

```
$str = "active=1 'oldest active'=0s disabled=0 'function call'=0";
print "\nBEF: $str\n";
$str =~s#active=1 'oldest active'=0s disabled=0 'function call'=0# my $tmp=$&; $tmp=~s/\'([^\']*)\'/my $tes=$&; $tes=~s{ }{\_}g; ($tes)/ge; $tmp=~s/ /\|/g; ($tmp); #ge;
print "\nAFT: $str\n";
```

May be some short ways will be there apart from this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F\' '{OFS=FS; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/ /,(i%2?"|":"_"),$i)}1' file
active=1|'oldest_active'=0s|disabled=0|'function_call'=0
```