# Using gsub to replace matches with same number of characters

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Is it possible to use gsub to replace each character of a match with another character? I have read and tried solutions from a lot of questions without success, because they were very specific to the example being used. Some that looked promising but ultimately did not get me there are

[gsub-replace-regex-match-with-regex-replacement-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395399/gsub-replace-regex-match-with-regex-replacement-string)

[replace-pattern-with-one-space-per-character-in-perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866072/replace-pattern-with-one-space-per-character-in-perl)

What I am looking for is a general way to do the following. I have a list of regexes, which I combine into a single regex expression of the form

```
pattern <- "[0-9]{3,}|[a-z]{3,}|..."
```

Given a string such as

```
x <- "1234 abc 12 a 123456"
```

I would like to get back from gsub the string with each character of a match replaced by #

```
"#### ### 12 a ######"
```

instead of

```
"# # 12 a #"
```

I have used `gsub` with the `perl` arg set to `TRUE`, and experimented with an online regex tool, using things like `\G` and lookarounds, but I cannot figure it out.

The reason I am looking for a way to do this with `gsub` (I realise it is easy to do in other ways) is to use it as a method of censoring certain words and matches such as dates, phone numbers and email addresses in a `dplyr` pipeline. The function I have works fine, except that any replacement is fixed, and I would like to replace each matching character, rather than each matching substring.

```
filter_words <- function(.data, .words, .replacement, ...) {
  .data %>% dplyr::mutate(
    dplyr::across(
      c(...),
      ~ gsub(
          paste0("\\b", .words, collapse = "|\\b"),
          .replacement, .,
          ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE
      )
    )
  )
}
```

I did try using a package called `mgsub` for the [`mgsub_censor`](https://github.com/cran/mgsub/blob/master/R/mgsub_censor.R) function it provides. This does work, but it is several orders of magnitude slower than what I already have, so not really practical for large datasets.

I did try creating a custom `gsub` function able to accept a function (that could return a string consisting of the same number of characters as each match) as the replacement argument. It worked fine for a single string, but failed to work in a pipe.

Comment: I tagged with perl since I am using gsub with perl=TRUE.

Comment: You need to state, at the beginning, the rule you are using for replacements. The only evidence for that is that you want to convert `"1234 abc 12 a 123456"` to `"#### ### 12 a ######"`. I can think of many rules that would achieve that: Two are the following: 1. convert every character in a string of 3 or more characters other than spaces to `'#'`; 2) 1. convert every character in a string of 3 or more letters or 4  or more digits to `'#'`. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - I think it is clear from the initial question: "...replace each character of a match with another character?". I have added what I want to get to the example anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may pass a function in `str_replace_all` and use `strrep` to repeat the `#` symbol `n` times.

```
x <- "1234 abc 12 a 123456"
pattern <- "[0-9]{3,}|[a-z]{3,}"

stringr::str_replace_all(x, pattern, function(m) strrep('#', nchar(m)))
#[1] "#### ### 12 a ######"
```

Comment: How would I add the equivalent of gsub's ignore.case please?

Comment: `stringr::str_replace_all(x, regex(pattern, ignore_case = TRUE), function(m) strrep('#', nchar(m)))`

Comment: Not bad, it is only 10 times slower than just replacing with a fixed replacement.